# Detecting URL called from android app

Tags: php, javascript, android, ios, browser

I have developped an app (ios and android) that does a php request to a server. For security reasons I need to make sure that a user cant type in the same URL in a browser. Only the app should be allowed to do this request. I have been thinking at doing javascript browser detection and I get a good result for ios where it answers "Unknown" when called from the app. But for android, it always answers "Android", be it within the browser or when called by the app.
Anyone out there having an idea on how to detect this on the server side?

Comment: Try adding a custom tag in the HTTP header.

Comment: Depends on the level of security you need but using the user-agent as identifier is not secure at all. You may be interested to search something about "hmac" and how to signing a request

Comment: Yep, have your app cryptographically sign requests.  Or better yet, go back to the drawing board and make it no longer a security concern for someone to browse to that URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could detect the user agent string. This can be done on the server side in PHP using:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
```

Android and iOS will return a user agent string containing stuff like "Mobile Safari", "webkit", etc. In your app, tell the webview to set the user agent as something proprietary that you've made up. You can do this on iOS with the following code - I expect Android has something similar:

```
[request setValue:@"MyMadeUpUserAgentString" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User_Agent"];
```

Then in PHP only show the page if the HTTP_USER_AGENT matches the value you've set in your app.

Of course it's not massively secure - some browsers or browser plugins let you fake your user agent. But it will stop the vast majority of users from seeing the content in a browser.

Comment: It's not secure at all; it's just an inconvenient barrier, like a 4-foot picket fence.  If that's enough for you, though, this is an easy solution.